# Docker ROS GUI tutorial

Tags: ros, docker, ros-kinetic, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have  been following the tutorial found here: http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI

I can get the insecure method working using `xhost +local:root` however, I am concerned about security, so would like to use the second method where you pass your /etc/passwd and such to the container. This, however, doesn't work for me, copying the example exactly. Has Docker changed since this was written to not allow this? Note: Due to volume mount time, the $USER field didn't work as it didn't find my user name, so I used my user id instead.

Docker version 19.03.4-ce, build 9013bf583a

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337793/docker-ros-gui-tutorial/) by [acwatkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/33822/acwatkins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorials where written quite a while ago, and in that time a number of projects have cropped up to simplify the task of using GUIs within docker. Rather than hacking on the Xserver and docker runtime arguments yourself, I'd recommend using a particular tool developed for this by OSRF called rocker:

https://github.com/osrf/rocker

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2019-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0